# local host 4000 given as default in environment variable

Tags: angular, postman

I am trying to understatnd login and registration using this code at.This code works fine when `ng serve` is run

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/04/28/angular-9-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

There the envirnment is set up as this.

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
};
```

In the account services login is declared as

```
 login(username, password) {
        return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.userSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

My doubt::
How come localhost:4000 work.I tried with postman and i am getting page not found response
How can i test this login method with postman.It is using local storage.Is it possible.Why is it given as port 4000 when i am running the app using port 4200. If this is a stupid question please ignore me.

Comment: 'apiUrl' is the backend API address

Comment: @G.WKalpaSathjanaDeSilva But why are we giving port no 4000

Comment: what are you using? fake backend?

Comment: @G.WKalpaSathjanaDeSilva I am tryig to understand this code.  https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/04/28/angular-9-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial .Does fake backend by default uses 4000 port.But i cant reproduce it with postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apiUrl` needs to point to where your backend code is running. Running ng serve will still have your angular code run at port `4200` by default, unless you set it otherwise. In order for port `4000` to work as you desire, you need to have some sort of backend server running there. Note that you will still open your browser to port `4200`, and just your code will make calls to port `4000`

I suggest if you are still having difficulty understanding what is going on here, you learn more about REST and http calls